# Update Database if textboxes are not empty

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

If the record is found, I would like my program to only update the textboxes which have text in them. The staff ID needs to be entered as the key field before being updated. The text boxes I have that can be used to update the database are First Name, Last Name, Address, DOB, Phone Number and email.

```
Private Sub btnSaveChanges_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveChanges.Click
    conn.Open()
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM StaffDetails WHERE StaffID='" & tbStaffID.Text & "'", conn)

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim sql, columns As String
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = conn.CreateCommand()

        If tbFirstName.Text = "" Then
        Else
            columns = columns & " FirstName = ? "
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", tbFirstName.Text)
        End If

        If tbLastName.Text = "" Then
        Else
            columns = columns & " LastName = ? "
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", tbLastName.Text)
        End If

        If tbDOB.Text = "" Then
        Else
            columns = columns & " DOB = ? "
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DOB", tbDOB.Text)
        End If

        If tbPhone.Text = "" Then
        Else
            columns = columns & " Number = ? "
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Number", tbPhone.Text)
        End If

        If tbAddress.Text = "" Then
        Else
            columns = columns & " Address = ? "
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address", tbAddress.Text)
        End If

        If tbEmail.Text = "" Then
        Else
            columns = columns & " Email = ? "
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", tbEmail.Text)
        End If


        If sql <> "" Then
            Dim da1 As New OleDbDataAdapter("UPDATE StaffDetails SET " & columns & " WHERE StaffID = " & tbStaffID.Text")
            cmd.Adapter.InsertCommand = cmd
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox("Staff ID not found")
    End If
    conn.Close()


End Sub
```

Comment: `End if` You've forgotten the ending statement.

Comment: BTW, Please show us what you've done so far.

Comment: Will get back in a minute, just trying a different way

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå question updated

Comment: da.Update() will update the database.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i will try again then update my code, if you could help afterward... many thanks  !

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå Updated my code above again, i dunno if it is clear to you yet what im trying to achieve... But is this right? can you edit my code im getting told there is a problem with adapter? will this update the database with textboxes which are not empty?

Comment: @T.S. Study the following page, [`DataAdapters and DataReaders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254931(v=vs.110).aspx), and report back if something's not working.

Comment: Please update your question and post the **exact** verbage of the error message.  "I'm getting told there is a problem with adapter" doesn't tell us enough.

Comment: You also want to check that the value of the text boxes isnt blank. String.IsNullOrWhitespace() takes care of both the null and empty checking.

Answer (score 0):

You really should use a parameterized query, to reduce your chance of errors or injection attacks.  Try the following code:

```
Private Sub btnSaveChanges_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveChanges.Click
   conn.Open()
   Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM StaffDetails WHERE StaffID='" & tbStaffID.Text & "'", conn)

   Dim dt As New DataTable
   da.Fill(dt)
   If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

      Dim sql, columns As string
      Dim cmd as OleDbCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
      If tbFirstName.Text <> "" Then
         columns = " FirstName = ? "
         cmd.Parameters.Add("FirstName", tbFirstName.Text)
      End If

      If tbLastName.Text <> "" Then
         If columns <> "" Then columns = columns & ", "
         columns = columns & " LastName = ? "
         cmd.Parameters.Add("LastName", tbLastName.Text)
      End If

      If tbDOB.Text <> "" Then
         If columns <> "" Then columns = columns & ", "
         columns = columns & " DOB = ? "
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DOB", tbDOB.Text)
      End If

      If tbPhone.Text <> "" Then
         If columns <> "" Then columns = columns & ", "
         columns = columns & " Number = ? "
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Number", tbPhone.Text)
      End If

      If tbAddress.Text <> "" Then
         If columns <> "" Then columns = columns & ", "
         columns = columns & " Address = ? "
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address", tbAddress.Text)
      End If

      If tbEmail.Text <> "" Then
         If columns <> "" Then columns = columns & ", "
         columns = columns & " Email = ? "
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", tbEmail.Text)
      End If

      If columns <> "" Then
         'add your own code to ensure that tbStaffID.txt does not contain something sinister, like a SQL attack command, etc.'
         cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE StaffDetails SET " & columns & " WHERE StaffID = " & tbStaffID.Text
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
      End If

   Else
       MsgBox("Staff ID not found")
   End If

   conn.Close()
   conn.Dispose() 'for good habits'
   cmd.Dispose()
   da.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: @bjorn-roger-kringsja In the question i have updated my code again... i have a problem with the adapter and update so its not running, is there any other problems with the code?

Comment: @bjorn-roger kringsja In the question i have updated my code again... i have a problem with the adapter and update so its not running, is there any other problems with the code?

Comment: Sorry.  In my original answer, I mixed up the use of the DataAdapter with the Command object.  I just updated my code so the command object runs by itself (to run the SQL update command).

Comment: Okay.  I revised my answer again, merging my code with yours.  You should be able to copy/paste it now.

Comment: still no luck could i email you my program?

Comment: Do not trust people on public forums with code (eg. don't email it to me and don't let me email it to you).  What error(s) are you getting?  Does it refer to any one of these lines?

Comment: @ tgolisch cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() not working, and two errors 
Warning 1 Unused local variable: 'sql'.
Warning 2 Variable 'columns' is used before it has been

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line that says "ExecuteNonQuery()".  Inspect the value of cmd.CommandText.  Copy that query (SQL) and try to run it in MS Access (new query, SQL view, run).  MS Access will give you a better idea of what is wrong with the SQL query.  My guess is that the column "Number" is a reserved word but it might be something else.  MSAccess will say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
If tbFirstName.Text Is Nothing Then
```

with

```
If tbFirstName.Text = "" Then
```

...if ..

...if ..

or do the check with something like: tbFirstName.Text.Length

Comment: @tgolisch In the question i have updated my code again... i have a problem with the adapter and update so its not running, is there any other problems with the code?

Comment: HaydenKThomas should send all the code (. aspx, .vb) and the error message.